# My commits appear as another user in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

I am trying to set up git on my laptop so I can push commits to GitHub. This now works, but if I do so and then visit GitHub, it appears as if some random user (always cbeaudoin898 - I have no idea who this is) made all the commits. It is super weird, I have no idea what is causing this.
When I push the commit, I log in with my own username & password. I also have this set in my git config. Here is an example repo: https://github.com/kmb5/etch-a-sketch

My git config:
[image: git config]
Screenshot of how a commit appears on GitHub:
[image: github screenshot]

Here is the commit log:
[image: commit log]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I am getting crazy, setting up GitHub was a pain as is, because I tried to set it up for 2 different GitHub accounts (work and private) - which was a hassle on its own.

Comment: May you share the output of a commit log which also shows the commit author? (`git log`)

Comment: hi @evolutionxbox sure, I just added it in the original post! it seems like I am committing it...

Comment: How did you make the commit? Have you configured the global email and global author? If you have two accounts, then you need to configure these setting in repository separately.

Comment: Hi @ChuckLu, I made the commit via `git push` from my terminal. Yes, the global email & author are both my email addresses. The two accounts are not the issue here (or at least I don't think so) - the issue is that the commits are made **by an entirely different GitHub user I don't recognize**

Comment: You might need to read this, [Why are my commits linked to the wrong user?](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user)

Comment: Thank you to ask this question.

Answer (score 16):

For anyone facing this issue please first check if you have a typo or wrong or a different email address configured in your local git. If so, then this might solve the issue as it did for my repo once upon a time.

### 1. To Verify Name and Email:

`git config --global user.name`

`git config --global user.email`

### 2. To Update Correctly:

`git config --global user.name "Your Correct Name Here"`

`git config --global user.email "Your Correct Email Here"`

### 3. Also repeat 1. and 2. without the --global option.

### 4. Now You Must Reset the Author

`git commit --amend --reset-author`

### 5. Finally can do Forced Push

`git push -f`

### 6. Verify on GitHub

### 7. Vote this answer if it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I was looking for this everywhere. hahaha

Comment: awesome , the only pain is you have to always do this

Comment: the only worked answer is this, thank you